# How to import standard libraries from a single file

Tags: python, module

I'm working on different project files and most of them are using similar libraries such as sys, time, os, re, requests. My question is how to import those similar libraries by referring to a single file instead of rewriting similar lines for each project file.

```
# Instead of doing this for file1.py, file2.py, file3.py
import sys
import re 
import os
import requests

# Is it possible to do on file1.py, file2.py, file3.py?
import modules from ('C:\...')
...
```

Comment: Your first example is widely considered best practice. Imports should be easy to read and trace.

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't do this because explicit is better than implicit but if you *really* wanted to you could have:

```
# imports.py
import foo
import bar
import baz
```

and then

```
# file1.py
from imports import *
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advise against this, since it isn't transparent to the reader at all what is happening, but in theory, you could do this via some file with a bunch of imports:

`somefile.py`

```py
import sys
import os
import requests
# and so on
```

`myfile.py`

```py
from somefile import *

print(os.path) # this will work
```